# Matlab - blocproc to copy an array via blocks

Tags: matlab, image-processing

read an image, 24-bit rgb
copy it blocks of 8x8 for example for each channel.
combine all 3 channels to get blocks of 8x8x3

how can I use blockproc to do this?

```
redChannel = I(:, :, 1);
greenChannel = I(:, :, 2);
blueChannel = I(:, :, 3);

%% output functions
funr = redChannel + greenChannel + blueChannel;
fung = S(:,:,2);
funb = S(:,:,3);
blockSize = [64 64];
@(block_struct) (block_struct.data) * ones(size(block_struct.data));

%% blocks
blockyImageR = blockproc(I, blockSize, funr)
blockyImageR = blockproc(redChannel, blockSize, fung)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are confused about [function handles](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html) and [anonymous functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html). Take a look at this example:

```
f = @(x) x+2;
```

In this example, variable `f` contains handle of an anonymous function that takes one argument and adds it to 2. After defining such a function, you can use it like regular functions:

```
A = 1:3;
B = f(a)
```

> ```
> B =
> 3     4     5
> ```

Now, there are functions that take arguments of type function handle and use them:

```
A = 1:3;
B = 2:4;
f = @(x, y) x*y;
C = arrayfun(f, A, B)
```

> ```
> C =  
> 2     6    12
> ```

Back to your question. [`blockproc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html) divides an image to blocks of specified size, applies the function to each block, and concatenates the results into a single image again. In following example, `fun` take an argument of type `structure` and adds all elements of `x.data` to a random number from [-50..50] interval. It just makes sure that results remain in [0..255] interval:

```
I = imread('peppers.png');
blockSize = [64 64];
fun = @(x) max(0, min(255, x.data + randi(100, 1)-50));
I2 = blockproc(I, blockSize, fun);
```

[image]

As you see, intensity of different blocks of image have been shifted randomly, but hue of pixels remained (almost) unchanged. That's because `fun` is called multiple times, each time shifting all channels of a block by same value. Now let's manipulate channels separately:

```
I3R = blockproc(I(:, :, 1), blockSize, fun);
I3G = blockproc(I(:, :, 2), blockSize, fun);
I3B = blockproc(I(:, :, 3), blockSize, fun);
I3 = cat(3, I3R, I3G, I3B);
```

[image]

Now both intensity and hue of blocks are shifted, since in this run each channel is shifted by a different value. Note that in previous example, `fun` takes blocks of size `64 by 64 by 3` but in second call(s) blocks are `64 by 64 by 1`.